# Grid with fixed height rows won't scroll in scrollview?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin forms in Visual Studio. I have a single grid 15 rows by 2 cols
and the row height is fixed at 180.This is nested inside a scrollview.
The grid of images is larger than the view, so i should be able to scroll down to see the images.

I've tried setting the vertical positions etc but it just wont scroll in the iOS simulator. I've wasted almost a whole day on this, can anybody help?

This is my code

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="EasyQuote.StyleList"
    Title = "Select Style">

    <ScrollView VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

        <Grid x:Name="showStylesGrid" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0"  >
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/> 
            <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image Source="CM1.png" Grid.Row="14" Grid.Column="0"/>
        </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks
Toby

Comment: Sorry, what specifically is not scaling? the images?

Comment: The images in the grid flow out of view, but I cant scroll to see them.

Comment: I am trying to acheive a grid of images with 2 images side by side. I am using code to read these in from a database and render them dynamically. This is why i am trying to use a grid. The included markup has the same issue as the dynamically updated version.

Comment: I also tried to create a series of 2 column, 1 row grids and add these to a stacklayout in a loop. That didn't work as i wasnt able to create a new grid per iteration of the loop.

Comment: Try removing VerticalOptions on your ScrollView they are FillAndExpand by default and I don't think I've ever seen StartAndExpand or CenterAndExpand ever work the way one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create scrollable item inside your grid then I think you have to use StackLayout. You can give a try.

```
<ScrollView>
   <stackLayout>
      <grid>
         ......
         ...... 
      </grid>
  <stackLayout>
</ScrollView
```

Comment: Its actually working now, thanks to anyone who had a think about this for me.

Comment: The issue was as follows... I was using code to fill the grid, then used the line Content = GridView to attach the view - this was the problem! I had already created the scrollview and grid in the XAML. Anyway if anybody else tries the hybrid approach be aware not to use the 'Content' if you have it already in XAML